# Using QGIS libraries to write standalone program in C#?

Tags: qgis, c#

I have investigate some liberaries which can help me to write stand alone applications.

Is there any way to use qgis liberaries in an standalone application which is written by C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really no. You only options for QGIS based applications are Python and C++, unless you want to build a web app which calls QGIS server to show the map then you can use what ever you want as it's just making WMS calls to the server.

Creating a standalone application with Python using QGIS is pretty easy.

Getting started with a standalone app in Python:

- I have an application ([Roam](https://github.com/DMS-Aus/Roam)) which is a standalone app.
- Another application of mine can profile QGIS projects and layers (https://github.com/DMS-Aus/qgis2img)
- Here is a guide I wrote about setting up PyCharm for PyQGIS support http://nathanw.net/2014/05/10/pycharm-pyqgis-qt/

If you are using QGIS 2.4 there is some handy application bootstrap logic:

```
from qgis.core.contextmanagers import qgisapp

def main(app):
   pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
   with qgisapp() as app:
       main(app)
```

That will take care of the bootstrapping logic normally needed to load QGIS into the right state.

(Sorry about all the plugs to my stuff, others feel free to add others)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.So I can create only using Python.Can you give me some hints where to start using Python and Qgis to create standalone applications?

Comment: See my updated post.

Comment: sir it is possible to make DLL in c# project that uses qgis for mapping?