# different way to build qgis python standalone application

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

There seems to be 2 different ways to start a Python QGIS standalone script.
The [official tutorial](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#python-applications) is using :

```
from qgis.core import *
# supply path to where is your qgis installed
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/path/to/qgis/installation", True)
# load providers
QgsApplication.initQgis()
```

But I have also seen code looking like this :

```
from qgis.core.contextmanagers import qgisapp
with qgisapp() as app:
    #do stuff
```

For example [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116935/using-qgis-libraries-to-write-standalone-program-in-c/116947#116947) and [here](http://kartoza.com/how-to-load-a-qgis-project-in-python/).

I didn't see any reference to the latter method on the official doc.

Does anybody know if there is a difference between the two ?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Trying to understand python with statement and context managers](http://sohu.io/questions/350254/trying-to-understand-python-with-statement-and-context-managers). I _think_ that the `contextmanager` allows users to re-use sets of code without having to repeat the exception handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source code for the context manager `qgisapp`:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/core/contextmanagers.py

you'll see it is just a neat wrapper for running code inside a `QgsApplication` context.

Following what Nathan W does with his Qgis python is usually a good idea, so I'd go with this.

Comment: Just to clarify, your ultimate suggestion is to use the context manager? Could you clarify a reference to "what Nathan W does"